# Extracting the name given as an argument from command line in Perl script

Tags: bash, perl, shell, command-line, command-line-arguments

I am new to the scripting languages, and I have a task that says I need to extract the name from a given argument from the command line in erl.

I am calling the Perl script like this

```
./perl.plx file.txt
```

and I need to get only that `file` name, not the whole `file.txt`

Comment: Try taking a look at `@ARGV`, it's an array with the parametres. It's in there.

Comment: Yes but look if I try using $ARGV[0] it returns **file.txt** and it's not of string type, so I can't use split by delimiter. So like I said, it gives me the whole **file.txt** and i need only the name of the **file**.

Comment: `@ARGV` only contains strings. It's what you do with them. So if you have `$ARGV[0]` with `file.txt`, then you can split that string `my $name = (split /\./, $ARGV[0])[0];` to have `$name` contain "file".

Comment: Thanks a lot @AntonH that code works.
I tried `($name) = split('.', $ARGV[0]);` before but it didn't worked i don't know why.

Comment: Because the character "." is a special character in regular expressions, it means 'any character'. To have it, you need to escape it, thus, `/\./`

Comment: Yes, i didn't thought that. Thanks a lot anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the name of the file, you need to extract it from `@ARGV`, and split it on the dot.

```
my $fileName = (split /\./, $ARGV[0])[0];
```

Explaination:

`split /\./, $ARGV[0]` splits on a dot (the character "." is a special character in regular expressions, it means 'any character'; to have it literally, you need to escape it, thus, `/\./`).

`(...)[0];` takes the first element, i.e. the file name.

Comment: Why use `split()` in preference to File::Basename?

Comment: @DaveCross Because I was responding quickly to OP's specific use case (it already took me a while to understand the exact issue, as you can see from my questions in comments). And, if I'm honest, I manipulate file names so little that I tend to forget about `File::`.

Answer (score 5):

The command line arguments to a Perl script appear in `@ARGV`, described in `perldoc perlvar`.

Parsing filenames seems trivial, but appearances may be misleading. However, Perl ships with a module called `File::Basename` that handles edge cases you might not immediately consider. One edge case that simple `split` wouldn't handle is the potential for dots to appear elsewhere in the filename aside from the final suffix.

You can review `File::Basename`'s documentation by typing `perldoc File::Basename` at the command prompt.

Here is an example:

```
use stict;
use warnings;
use File::Basename qw(fileparse);

my ($fname, $dirs, $suffix) = fileparse($ARGV[0], qr/\.txt/);

print "Base file name is $fname\n";
print "Suffix is $suffix\n";
print "Path to $fname$suffix is $dirs\n";
```

Because this module ships with Perl, you don't need to install anything to use it.  In taking advantage of the core Perl modules that ship with every Perl distribution, you leverage best practices and debugging embodied within these tools.

Comment: Thanks. As I said, I am new to `perl` and especially to things like command line arguments. But thanks a lot for this, was helpful a lot.